# Windows 8 and Windows phone 8 code reuse issue

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-8, visual-studio-2013

I have a Windows Phone 8 (XAML/C#) app and a Windows 8(HTML/JS) app.

Both apps are very different visually, but they consume the same data from a JSON API service.
What would be the best approach (in time, effort and money) to engage the development of these apps?

Example:

- Can i write only once the "JSON API/Connection/Serialization/DataModels/etc Code" and reuse it in both apps? (Maybe doing a portable class library)
- Should i use XAML for both apps? Javascript for both apps? to unify code languages?
- Should i have only one solution containing a WP8 project, and a W8 project?
- What's with Windows RT? Will my Windwos 8 app run in WindowsRT?

Comment: You should take a look at [Universal apps](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/building-universal-Windows-apps) in VS 2013 for Windows 8.1 and Windows phone 8.1. You have to build your app as x86 and ARM for Windows phone 8.x, and you build your app as x86 and ARM (and optionally x64) for Windows 8.x and Windows RT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is :-

1. You should make `portable class library` (PCL) for your common code. As
   PCLs are made for code reuse.
2. I think it is not much crucial what are using for UI, it is up to
   you in which are good.
3. You should not make same project for `Windows 8` and `WP8`. don't mix up
   things here because there are lot of differences between these two
   platforms. In the end you don't want that if you changes for Windows
   8 and your WP8 apps stops working. don't create trouble for
   yourself.
4. What I think for Win-RT is - it is at the edge of death. So don't
   worry about them too much. In future everything going to be unified.

Note- I strongly recommend you PCLs for your common code. If something is not supported in PCLs then create separate projects(may be specific to platforms) and reuse them.

Hope it help you somehow.

Comment: In case i make a portable Class library, should i have it in a separate solution? How would i deal with source control on that library?

Comment: PCL is same as that of other projects. so make a PCL project separately and add that to your project . For handling Source Control there is subtree concept in git. You can see that. I was using the TFS before in which I directly add them to source control. And i have little knowledge about SC.

Comment: So i will have my Windwos phone solution. With a reference to the PCL DLL and then another solution with the Windows 8 app, also with a reference to the PLC DLL. And finally, another Solution with the PCL? Total of three solutions.?